# "Difference in" or "difference to"?

Tags: prepositions

Of the two choices of preposition in bold in the sentence below which one is correct?

- Having a university degree will make a difference **to**/**in** your career?

Comment: Both are grammatically correct, and the meaning is practically identical too. As for factual correctness, probably not, in the long run.

Comment: **To** indicates the object that receives the difference. **In** = during or within.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use;

**To**, if you were saying the university degree would change the type of work you did.

&

**In**, if you were saying the university degree would change the *way* you worked in that career.